# Use IntentService to perform a repeated tasks

Tags: android, service

I have to perform a repeated tasks (download data from internet) in a Service. I did the task with the following code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandler.post(mTask);
    return START_STICKY;
    }

    private final Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
        downloadData(url); 
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, mDelay);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
    }
}
```

If I want to use an IntentService instead a service and move `mHandler.post(mTask);` to onHandleIntent the code is executed only 1 time because then the IntentService is killed.

```
@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandler.post(mTask);
}
```

Can I prevent this and make the IntentService running?

Answer (score 2):

If the service overall will not be around very long, and if `mDelay` is short (a minute or less), you may just want to stick with your original implementation.

If `mDelay` is long, you should use `AlarmManager`, so your service is only in memory while it is doing work. In that case, the `AlarmManager` alarm is handing the periodic repeat.